# CSS - my table (made with flex) moves when I open an popover window

Tags: css, angular

So situation is that my table moves when I open an popover window. As a popover window I am using this popover window: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-confirmation-popover

I am using Angular for this project. I tried adding some css styles but nothing does help. But I am sure it could be solved but I am not here yet.

Page looks like this:[image]

When I open popover it transforms to this:
[image]

My HTML code is:

```
<div
  class="list-view-playlist"
>
  <fa-icon
    mwlConfirmationPopover
    [popoverTitle]="popoverTitle"
    [popoverMessage]="popoverMessage"
    placement="right"
    (confirm)="removeFromBookmarks()"
    (cancel)="cancelClicked = true"
    *ngIf="isBookmark"
    class="ms-1 me-1"
    [icon]="faBookmarkSolid"
  ></fa-icon>
  <img
    [src]="imageUrl"
    alt="video-img"
  />
  <div class="about-video">
    <h4>
      <a>{{ video.title }}</a>
    </h4>
    <p>{{ video.author.name }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="uploaded">
    <p>{{ video.published }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="views">
    <p>{{ video.views }} Views</p>
  </div>
  <div class="category">
    <app-badge [text]="video.type"></app-badge>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the css part:

```
.list-view-playlist {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 150px 40% 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 4px;

  img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 0.75rem;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .about-video {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 1rem;
  }

  .category {
    div {
      width: min-content;
    }
  }

  .category,
  .uploaded,
  .views {
    justify-self: center;
  }
}

fa-icon {
  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

mwl-confirmation-popover-window {
  .popover {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid $text-grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    .confirm-btns {
      margin-top: 1rem;
      .confirm-btn-container {
        flex-basis: 0%;
      }

      .btn-outline-secondary {
        color: #1f2937;
        border: solid 1px #e5e7eb;
      }
    }
  }   
}
```

Thanks to everyone for help!

Comment: Without seeing the rendered HTML it’s hard to know exactly what the problem is but it looks as though an extra element is being added which the flex is accommodating. Try wrapping the icon in a div to see what happens.

Comment: Oh yes, write this as an answer so I can accept it! :D If I wrap the icon in div, problem is solved. Thanks

Comment: You can also use @angular/cdk `Overlay` for this type of jobs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the rendered HTML it’s hard to know exactly what the problem is but it looks as though an extra element is being added which the flex is accommodating.

Try wrapping the icon in a div to see what happens.

Comment: Thank you! It solved my problem. If you think my question could help anyone, feel free to vote it! Thanks